# No Voice commands on cisco router

Tags: router, cisco-ios, packet-tracer, license

I cannot find voice commands on my router,
I have licenced it but no voice commands or sip are found

Its on packet tracer.

Cisco router 2911

Thank you

Comment: Do you have any VoIP hardware installed on the router?

Comment: Have you reloaded since enabling the voice license? It's also possible PT simply doesn't support voice.

Comment: No i dont have ant VoIP hardware installed on the router. 
Do i need to connect something?
commands such as voice service voip or sip-ua are not found

Comment: @Ricky yes, I have reloaded and even shudown

Comment: If you do not have the hardware that the command support, then you will not have the commands.

Comment: @RonMaupin i see, so which hardware could that be ?

Comment: Things like PVDMs, VWICs, etc. that are used for VoIP communications. You also want the Unified Communications license, and possibly the SRST/CME license.

Comment: What version of PT? I've seen labs using 7.2/7.3 and 2811/2911. The uck9 pack has to be enabled to use voice on the 2911. (accept eula, etc., etc. "wr mem", reload...)